# What does i=1<<i mean in C?

Tags: c

I have this source code:

```
void main() {
  int a[10]={9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}; int i;
  for (i=0; i<10; i=1<<i) a[9-i]=a[i];
  for (i=1; i<10; i++) a[0]+=a[i];
  printf("%d", a[0]);
}
```

Since I'm new to C programming, I don't really understand what it does. What does `i=1<<i` mean in the for loop?

Comment: `<<` is the bitwise left shift operator. (And `void main()` is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`.)

Comment: `i` will take on the values 0, 1, 2, 4, 16. 16 > 10, so that will end the loop.

Comment: Yeah I thought that void main() is wrong too but what I'm looking at is the last years exam questions. I'm trying to prepare for the first step of the exam which is held over the whole country but the problem is I have been learning Python, and I'm pretty new to C.

Comment: They put that code on an exam?!

Comment: I'm wondering what the intent of the code snippet is?  Is is supposed to be a puzzle or is it supposed to be trying to teach something in a confusing way?

Comment: Question asks what will be the output. And yeah they put it on the exam, with the correct indentations of course. Those not indented nested for loops are because of copy paste.

Comment: The indentation is correct (though the layout is ugly). Those `for` loops are not nested.

Comment: The proper answer to "what does this C program do" is to answer: "The C standard imposes no requirements, as the prototype of `main` is not one of those defined in the standard."

Answer (score 4):

`1<<i` is the bitwise left shift operator. If you think of 1 as 00001 it says to shift the 1 left by `i` times. The loop feeds the result back into itself.

- `1<<0` is 00001 or 1.
- `1<<1` is 00010 or 2.
- `1<<2` is 00100 or 4.
- `1<<4` is 10000 or 16.

It starts at 0 and stops at 4, because 16 is greater than 10.

You can see this in action by doing the same loop and printing `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i=1<<i) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why you would do this, I'm not sure.

Comment: Except that the loop skips 8 because `1 << 4` is 16.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Righto, I forgot it has a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `<<` is known as left-shift. It shifts bits to the left in its first argument by the number of places given in the second argument. Its actions are only defined for unsigned types. In your code, `i` is shifted to the left by 1 place, and the result of the shifting is placed back in `i`. This is the same as multiplying by powers of 2.

Also, you should write `int main()`. The `void` version is wrong and non-standard.

Comment: `int main(void)` is better than `int main()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson ...why?

Comment: @KeithThompson how is it better?

Comment: `int main() { /* ... */ }` is an old-style definition that doesn't specify the number of type(s) of the expected arguments. `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` uses a *prototype*, which explicitly says that `main` takes no arguments. Though it's a minor point, this can catch errors if you call `main` recursively (yes, that's legal). A more major point is that the C Standard says that `int main(void)` is valid; it doesn't say the same about `int main()`. I've written about this at some length [here](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2014/02/c-standard-quibbles.html).

Comment: @KeithThompson I was curious to know, thanks I will look into that

Answer (score 1):

the left shift operator `<<` has higher precedence in C than `=`.

So first the value `1` (0x00000001)  is shifted left the number of bits (per the count in `i`.

The result is then assigned back into `i`